# Why does PHP code get ignored in one of my three .php files.?

Tags: php

It's a weather reporting web-page. Just to see what I can do. There are three *iframes*, 
The first includes a listing of some of the parameters in an JSON file from an API. I works just the way I expected.

The second is a chart of data -  a different API call from the first one. No problems there.

The third will be forecast data, but the PHP code in the file is ignored! Every time!

This is the code (I've shortened it by eliminating the formatting and printing):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style/weather.css" />
        <title>The Weather Report</title>
<!--[if IE]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/Florida.css" />

    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        print "ready";

        $forecast = get_web_page("http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=1a134310341ff3b6fadb73bd1967baca&query=34232");

        print $forecast;

        $arrWeather = json_decode($forecast, true);
        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

All the HTML shows in wheen I view the age source"

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style/weather.css" />
        <title>The Weather Report</title>
<!--[if IE]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/Florida.css" />

    </head>
    <body>
        ready
```

That's it! The API request works perfectly when I plug it directly into the browser.

Comment: You are getting a fatal PHP error. Check your logs. We also can't help you since we don't know what `get_web_page()` actually does.

Comment: Alternatively to checking the logs like @JohnConde suggested, you could try to run the code with error_reporting and display_errors enabled:

`error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` should get you an error message on screen.

Comment: There are no errors identified in the logs, even with all the reporting turned ON.

'file_get_contents' is similar (I guess) to 'get_web_page.' Either works in the files that work; neither works in the file that fails.